# Spring Reactor benefits when Number of Publisher threads is much higher than number of consumers

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, reactor

I have the following use case:

- N threads publish data (N can range from 10 to 1000 threads), those thread can make HTTP request, jdbc calls, pure java processing using only local computer
- 1 to M thread consume it making IOs (send HTTP requests, write to Database... possibliy in bulk) , those threads should not slowdown the publishers. M must not exceed 10 threads.

N threads may publish data much faster than consumer will consume it, but the idea is to minimize the slowdowns of publisher.

I have implemented an approach based on ArrayBlockingQueue where publisher write, and a thread that takes data our of the queue and processes it, it works but results are not great.

I am thus studying the Reactor pattern and particularly Spring-Reactor to see if it could be a response to my use case. It is the case ?

I read :

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-reactor/#initial => This one does not seems to meet my use-case.
- https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-core/src/test/java/reactor/core/processor/ProcessorThroughputTests.java => Seems closer to mine but need confirmation

In my situation where number of publisher threads is much higher than number of consumers is it the right choice ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to look at Reactor's [`PersistentQueue` facility](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-core/src/test/groovy/reactor/queue/PersistentQueueSpec.groovy) and separate your Publisher from your Subscriber across that. It's a normal `Queue` implementation but it uses the Chronicle Queue for persistence, fail-over, and replayability. It is also extremely, extremely fast.

You would basically have publisher pushing data into the PersistentQueue from one side and a set of subscribers pulling from it on the other. It might be a drop-in replacement for your current use if you're already using a `Queue`.

I need to write a wiki page on it to show some basic use patterns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. Yes I think a wiki page would be great. As a new user of library it sounds promising but from my view lacks of documentation currently. Some concepts should be explained for beginners in this fields and also some focus on which part are thread-safe and which are not.

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with a similar issue using a custom container class. It uses double-buffering methodology via a CAS object that allows you to read all accumulated objects in one lock-free action.

I have no idea how efficient it is but it's simplicity should ensure it is up there with the good ones.

Note that most of the code below is test code - you can remove all code below the `//TESTING` comment without affecting the functionality.

```
/**
 * Lock free - thread-safe.
 *
 * Write from many threads - read with fewer threads.
 *
 * Write items of type T.
 *
 * Read items of type List<T>.
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 * @param <T> - Th etype we plan to write/read.
 */
public class DoubleBufferedList<T> {

    /**
     * Atomic reference so I can atomically swap it through.
     *
     * Mark = true means I am adding to it so momentarily unavailable for iteration.
     */
    private final AtomicMarkableReference<List<T>> list = new AtomicMarkableReference<>(newList(), false);

    // Factory method to create a new list - may be best to abstract this.
    protected List<T> newList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Get and replace the current list.
     *
     * Used by readers.
     *
     * @return List<T> of a number (possibly 0) of items of type T.
     */
    public List<T> get() {
        // The list that was there.
        List<T> it;
        // Replace an unmarked list with an empty one.
        if (!list.compareAndSet(it = list.getReference(), newList(), false, false)) {
            // Mark was not false - Failed to replace!
            // It is probably marked as being appended to but may have been replaced by another thread.
            // Return empty and come back again soon.
            return Collections.<T>emptyList();
        }
        // Successfull replaced an unmarked list with an empty list!
        return it;
    }

    /**
     * Grab and lock the list in preparation for append.
     *
     * Used by add.
     */
    private List<T> grab() {
        List<T> it;
        // We cannot fail so spin on get and mark.
        while (!list.compareAndSet(it = list.getReference(), it, false, true)) {
            // Spin on mark - waiting for another grabber to release (which it must).
        }
        return it;
    }

    /**
     * Release the grabbed list.
     *
     * Opposite of grab.
     */
    private void release(List<T> it) {
        // Unmark it - should this be a compareAndSet(it, it, true, false)?
        if (!list.attemptMark(it, false)) {
            // Should never fail because once marked it will not be replaced.
            throw new IllegalMonitorStateException("It changed while we were adding to it!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add an entry to the list.
     *
     * Used by writers.
     *
     * @param entry - The new entry to add.
     */
    public void add(T entry) {
        List<T> it = grab();
        try {
            // Successfully marked! Add my new entry.
            it.add(entry);
        } finally {
            // Always release after a grab.
            release(it);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add many entries to the list.
     *
     * @param entries - The new entries to add.
     */
    public void add(List<T> entries) {
        List<T> it = grab();
        try {
            // Successfully marked! Add my new entries.
            it.addAll(entries);
        } finally {
            // Always release after a grab.
            release(it);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a number of entries.
     *
     * @param entries - The new entries to add.
     */
    @SafeVarargs
    public final void add(T... entries) {
        // Make a list of them.
        add(Arrays.<T>asList(entries));
    }

    // TESTING.
    // How many testers to run.
    static final int N = 10;
    // The next one we're waiting for.
    static final AtomicInteger[] seen = new AtomicInteger[N];
    // The ones that arrived out of order.
    static final ConcurrentSkipListSet<Widget>[] queued = Generics.<ConcurrentSkipListSet<Widget>>newArray(N);

    static class Generics {

        // A new Generics method for when we switch to Java 7.
        @SafeVarargs
        static <E> E[] newArray(int length, E... array) {
            return Arrays16.copyOf(array, length);
        }
    }

    static {
        // Populate the arrays.
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            seen[i] = new AtomicInteger();
            queued[i] = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();
        }
    }

    // Thing that is produced and consumed.
    private static class Widget implements Comparable<Widget> {

        // Who produced it.
        public final int producer;
        // Its sequence number.
        public final int sequence;

        public Widget(int producer, int sequence) {
            this.producer = producer;
            this.sequence = sequence;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return producer + "\t" + sequence;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Widget o) {
            // Sort on producer
            int diff = Integer.compare(producer, o.producer);
            if (diff == 0) {
                // And then sequence
                diff = Integer.compare(sequence, o.sequence);
            }
            return diff;
        }
    }

    // Produces Widgets and feeds them to the supplied DoubleBufferedList.
    private static class TestProducer implements Runnable {

        // The list to feed.
        final DoubleBufferedList<Widget> list;
        // My ID
        final int id;
        // The sequence we're at
        int sequence = 0;
        // Set this at true to stop me.
        public volatile boolean stop = false;

        public TestProducer(DoubleBufferedList<Widget> list, int id) {
            this.list = list;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Just pump the list.
            while (!stop) {
                list.add(new Widget(id, sequence++));
            }
        }
    }

    // Consumes Widgets from the suplied DoubleBufferedList
    private static class TestConsumer implements Runnable {

        // The list to bleed.
        final DoubleBufferedList<Widget> list;
        // My ID
        final int id;
        // Set this at true to stop me.
        public volatile boolean stop = false;

        public TestConsumer(DoubleBufferedList<Widget> list, int id) {
            this.list = list;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // The list I am working on.
            List<Widget> l = list.get();
            // Stop when stop == true && list is empty
            while (!(stop && l.isEmpty())) {
                // Record all items in list as arrived.
                arrived(l);
                // Grab another list.
                l = list.get();
            }
        }

        private void arrived(List<Widget> l) {
            for (Widget w : l) {
                // Mark each one as arrived.
                arrived(w);
            }
        }

        // A Widget has arrived.
        private static void arrived(Widget w) {
            // Which one is it?
            AtomicInteger n = seen[w.producer];
            // Don't allow multi-access to the same producer data or we'll end up confused.
            synchronized (n) {
                // Is it the next to be seen?
                if (n.compareAndSet(w.sequence, w.sequence + 1)) {
                    // It was the one we were waiting for! See if any of the ones in the queue can now be consumed.
                    for (Iterator<Widget> i = queued[w.producer].iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                        Widget it = i.next();
                        // Is it in sequence?
                        if (n.compareAndSet(it.sequence, it.sequence + 1)) {
                            // Done with that one too now!
                            i.remove();
                        } else {
                            // Found a gap! Stop now.
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Out of sequence - Queue it.
                    queued[w.producer].add(w);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Main tester
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            System.out.println("DoubleBufferedList:Test");
            // Create my test buffer.
            DoubleBufferedList<Widget> list = new DoubleBufferedList<>();
            // All running threads - Producers then Consumers.
            List<Thread> running = new LinkedList<>();
            // Start some producer tests.
            List<TestProducer> producers = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                TestProducer producer = new TestProducer(list, i);
                Thread t = new Thread(producer);
                t.setName("Producer " + i);
                t.start();
                producers.add(producer);
                running.add(t);
            }

            // Start the same number of consumers (could do less or more if we wanted to).
            List<TestConsumer> consumers = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                TestConsumer consumer = new TestConsumer(list, i);
                Thread t = new Thread(consumer);
                t.setName("Consumer " + i);
                t.start();
                consumers.add(consumer);
                running.add(t);
            }
            // Wait for a while.
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            // Close down all.
            for (TestProducer p : producers) {
                p.stop = true;
            }
            for (TestConsumer c : consumers) {
                c.stop = true;
            }
            // Wait for all to stop.
            for (Thread t : running) {
                System.out.println("Joining " + t.getName());
                t.join();
            }
            // What results did we get?
            int totalMessages = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                // How far did the producer get?
                int gotTo = producers.get(i).sequence;
                // The consumer's state
                int seenTo = seen[i].get();
                totalMessages += seenTo;
                Set<Widget> queue = queued[i];
                if (seenTo == gotTo && queue.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Producer " + i + " ok.");
                } else {
                    // Different set consumed as produced!
                    System.out.println("Producer " + i + " Failed: gotTo=" + gotTo + " seenTo=" + seenTo + " queued=" + queue);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Total messages " + totalMessages);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```